# maven could not resolve project dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, resolve

When i try to make a mvn deploy i am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project cross-automation-config: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.desp.cross.commons:cross-automation-config:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.desp.qc:automation-commons-config:jar:0.0.7 (compile), com.desp.cross.commons:cross-automation-utils:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.desp.cross.commons:cross-automation-utils:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.desp.cross.commons:cross-automation-commons:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repo.jenkins-ci.org has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Into the project (cross-automation-config) i have these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.desp.qc</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation-commons-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.desp.cross.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>cross-automation-utils</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This project has a parent project, which i don't considerate necessary to put in here.

I know that this is a dependencies problem. What i don't understand is why eclipse can download those dependencies, without any error, and maven can not

Do you have an idea about what is going on?

Comment: i've already checked settings.xml and is not a problem from the repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your maven is not able to find this dependencies in your local repository.
You should try to build first those two projects: `automation-commons-config` and `cross-automation-utils` (be careful if there are dependent in each other).